# How to refresh image automatically on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, typescript, aurelia

I'm trying to get a image (from a ipcam) on a webpage and automatically refresh it. I have made a backend that has a function that reads a image and returns it. this works and looks like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
[System.Web.Http.Route("dummymethod3")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Get image 3");
    ddEngine.sem.WaitOne();

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\user1\\TestProject\\\\bin\\Debug\\testimage.png";
    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)); // this file stream will be closed by lower layers of web api for you once the response is completed.
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");     


    ddEngine.sem.Release();

    return response;

}
```

This function works and returns the image. On the client side i have controller that calls a update method that gets the image.

```
  activate(){
      setInterval(this.updateStatus.bind(this), 1000);
  }

   updateStatus = function () {
      this.statusService.getImage()
        .then(data => this.message = data);
  }
```

And the `getImage` method looks like this:

```
getImage() {
     return this.client.get(baseUrl)
        .then(response => {
           return response.content;
    });
}
```

The html looks like this and displays the first image corectly.

```
    <template>
    </script>
   <img id="img" src= "http://localhost:8080/api/status/dummymethod3" />
</template>
```

In my custom OWIN middleware i add a no cache value.

```
    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    context.Response.Headers["MachineName"] = Environment.MachineName;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("CACHE-CONTROL", new[] {"NO-CACHE"});

    await Next.Invoke(context);
}
```

When pressing F5 it reload the entire page and gets a new image. I see that the ineval method is called and the backend call is called. But the image is not refreshed.

Does anyone have a idea how to refresh the image? Any idea's are welcome!

Comment: try adding a time and date stamp to the end of the image url, the image might be appear to be the same due to it being cached.

Comment: Thank you for you're comment, where do i need to add it? Since the actual call "http://localhost:8080/api/status/dummymethod3?" + datetime makes that the method is not called anymore, it can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a bit mixed up with how you're trying to solve your problem.

You're using the `getImage()` method but then not doing anything with the results. So even if that's being triggered every second - it won't actually do anything.

You can use `src.bind` and then a function to refresh the URL to reload the image without needing to call the image via an API.

Your HTML;

```
<img id="img" src.bind="imagePath" />
```

Your Javascript;

```
imagePath = '';

activate(){
    setInterval(this.updateImageSrc.bind(this), 1000);
}

updateImageSrc() {
    let dt = new Date();
    let baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/status/dummymethod3";
    this.imagePath = baseUrl + "?t=" + dt.getTime();
}
```

This will create a new URL for your image every second by updating a dummy query parameter. Using `src.bind` will ensure this URL is continually updated.